# Prevent xbindkeys to work in terminal

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, emacs, fedora

I try to implement Emacs keybindings in my browser.
Currently I have `.xbindkeysrc` and this chord

```bsh
"if [[ "$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)" =~ "Chrome" ]]; then xdotool key --window "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" Left; fi"                                                                 
  control+b
```

It works well in Chrome, if I press `ctrl + b` the caret goes backward but then I have a weird aftereffect: I can't use `ctrl + b` in my terminal anymore (Gnome Terminal).
Aside I don't know why this happens, is there a way to prevent xbindkeys to block keys in a certain program ?
If not, do you think about another way to work around this ?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Additional Notes** :

- Not only the key is blocked in `Gnome Terminal` but also in `rxvt` and `xterm`. And if I remove the conditional part and type

```
"xdotool key --window "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" Left"
  control+b
```

only, the chord still is blocked in terminals (and even in Gedit) when I expect it to work. That really confuses me.

- I also tried **xmodmap** but the keysyms table doesn't include the control key, it's not then possible.
  I still try to make it work using `xbindkeys` and `xdotool`, if you could help me I would really appreciate that.
- The problem seems to be **Xorg** related because trying the same script in a **Wayland** context works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested about this question, here's how I finally do it.

Instead of trying to include the conditional part in the `.xbindkeysrc` directly I made a separate script that will loop fast enough to run or kill `xbindkey` daemon

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/sh

while true
do
    if [[ "$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)" =~ "Chrome" ]]
    then
        xbindkeys 2>/dev/null
    else
        killall xbindkeys 2>/dev/null
    fi
    sleep 0.5
done
```

Then in my `.xbindkeysrc` I write all the Emacs chords.
And also I use `systemd` to run the script on startup.

Hope it helped you.